# IntelliJ/Android Studio: Two instances?

Tags: intellij-idea, android-studio

Basic question: is it possible to start up both an instance of  android studio and  intelliJ at once?

Comment: Can't you try it out yourself?

Comment: Sorry, I had to change the properties of windows task bar.  damn windows!